# Linux commands to use Windows bootloader instead of Grub

Tags: boot, command-line, grub2, windows, bootloader

So, I can't boot into windows at the moment, and in order to fix this problem I need to access Advanced Options which I can do by pressing F8 in the windows boot loader. However, I have grub currently as the default boot loader. How would I be able to change the bootloader through Linux terminal? Any ideas appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this command

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

and change the GRUB_DEFAULT to what windows boot loader is.

Comment: This changes the entry that is highlighted by default in Grub. It doesn't change the bootloader.

Comment: whoops..., kinda got confused

Comment: Well, i think you need a flash drive to boot windows. That is sad truth. I learned this the hard way: I tried to install ubuntu and boot windows. You need either a flash drive or you have to rewrite the MBR to boot windows :(

Answer (score 0):

Have you try boot-repair?

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install boot-repair
```

Run boot-repair, choose Recommended Repair. At least this will make you can boot to your Windows by Grub.

Then if you want to change the default bootloader, you can use [EasyBCD](http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/) to change the default bootloader. See [this](https://neosmart.net/wiki/easybcd/basics/) for the documentation.

Comment: Thank You! I haven't tried this out yet but something like EasyBCD was EXACTLY what i was looking for. I will try the boot repair first though!

Comment: Is there a CentOS equivalent to the commands? Also, EasyBCD can only be installed on windows. I found kgrubeditor as a linux alternative.

Comment: @NavjotSingh EasyBCD is Windows software. I mean, try using boot-repair first, to make you able to boot into your Windows. Then on Windows, use EasyBCD to change the default boot loader. So my post is 2 step work. For CentOS, you should ask in [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/)